# Making a new dataframe based on certain conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe object in **R**, sample of which is as follows:

```
4   5   3
4   5   9
4   5   2
4   6   4
4   10  4
4   10  3
4   10  7
4   10  2
4   9   3
4   9   7
4   10  4
4   10  3
4   6   8
4   5   4
12  3   6
12  4   1
12  4   2
12  4   7
```

From this dataframe, I want to create a new dataframe of **20** columns, as follows:

1. Only one row in the new dataframe,for each unique value in `$1`. Hence for this sample data, the new dataframe should have 2 rows(unique 4,12).
2. `$2` represents the column number of the new dataframe, in which the value of `$3`(of this dataframe) is to be filled. If there are repeating cases, the median of the values of `$3` is to be taken. For example, for 
   `$1` value 4, 5 is repeated 4 times, and in the new dataframe, column 5 of the first row should have the value median(3,9,2,4) =3.
3. All other column values are zero.

A sample output for this data would be as follows:

```
0 0 0 0 3 4 0 0 3 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 3 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

How can we do this in R? A huge thanks in advance!

Comment: how can the median of `(3,9,2,4) ` be `3` and how can the median of `c(4,8)` be 4??

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your expected outcome is correct? I think there is an error in calculating the median in your question, as also pointed out in the comments. You could do it as follows:

```
library(dplyr)

df$V1 <- as.numeric(as.factor(df$V1))
values <- df %>% group_by(V1,V2) %>% summarise(median=median(V3))
new_df <- matrix(0,nrow=length(unique(df$V1)), ncol=20)

for(i in 1:nrow(new_df)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(new_df)){
    value <- values$median[values$V1==i & values$V2==j]
    if(length(value)>0){
      new_df[i,j] = value  
    }
  }
}

new_df

    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
[1,]    0    0    0    0  3.5    6    0    0    5   3.5     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[2,]    0    0    6    2  0.0    0    0    0    0   0.0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

The outcome is slightly different though.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = transform(df,V1=factor(V1))
fill = matrix(0,length(levels(df$V1)),20)
df2=aggregate(V3~.,df,function(x)floor(median(x)))
fill[cbind(as.integer(df2$V1),df2$V2)]=df2$V3
fill
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    3    6    0    0    5     3     0     0     0     0
[2,]    0    0    6    2    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
     [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
[1,]     0     0     0     0     0     0
[2,]     0     0     0     0     0     0
```